# What is MySQL best way to partition the archive table?

Tags: partition

I have below table and want to partition this table please suggest the better way. this table will be use in joins mostly with Problemid column. This table will have history of the each problemid/ticket i.t at what time this ticket moved to with state etc.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `sd_servicerequest_history` (
  `ProblemId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CurrentTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `NatureOfChange` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ActionPerformedBy` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `HistoryID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `OldValue` varchar(5120) NOT NULL,
  `NewValue` varchar(5120) NOT NULL,
  `Parameter` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `FIELDID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ChildOf` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `OldStateID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NewStateID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Userid` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`HistoryID`),
  KEY `FK_servicehistory_ProblemId` (`ProblemId`),
  KEY `ChildOfIndex` (`ChildOf`),
  KEY `Userid` (`Userid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_servicehistory_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Userid`) REFERENCES `userdetails` (`userid`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_servicehistory_ProblemId` FOREIGN KEY (`ProblemId`) REFERENCES `sd_servicereqmaster` (`ProblemId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have tried partition using problemid but I can not pass the problemid in where clause

Comment: Whats the main reason you want to partition? As MySQL should be able to handle in the billions of records number just fine without partitions assuming indexes are used..

Comment: Thanks for your response, since this a history table and data is never going to purge, in some setup it has reached up to 9 cores rows. In case, if it using index also queries are slow because number of rows scanning is more.

Comment: *"if it using index also queries are slow because number of rows scanning is more."* Can you show a query/queries also which you run and can you explain those with `EXPLAIN query` .. Also you still need to add the other tables which are used in the foreign keys ..Number of records in the table also can be important to know and also give a time how long it takes what you can "slow"... As that information is more or less required for a performance question..

Comment: explain SELECT distinct h.problemid
FROM sd_servicerequest_history h,sd_servicereqmaster s ,sd_statecategory_details sd,sd_service l
where h.NewStateID=sd.stateid and s.currentstatus=sd.stateid and sd.statecategoryid in(1234)
and h.problemID = s.ProblemID and s.ProjectID = 1 and s.ServiceID=l.ServiceID
and h.CurrentTime Between '2019-04-01' and '2019-08-01'

Comment: 1, 'SIMPLE', 'h', '', 'ALL', 'FK_servicehistory_ProblemId', '', '', '', 1, 100.00, 'Using where; Using temporary' 1, 'SIMPLE', 's', '', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY,Current_Status,FK_sd_servicereqmaster_1,FK_sd_servicereqmaster_2', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'ims.h.ProblemId', 1, 100.00, 'Using where; Distinct'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'sd', '', 'ref', 'FK_sd_statecategory_details_1,StateCategoryID', 'FK_sd_statecategory_details_1', '4', 'ims.h.NewStateID', 1, 100.00, 'Using index condition; Using where; Distinct' 1, 'SIMPLE', 'l', '', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'ims.s.ServiceID', 1, 100.00, 'Using index; Distinct'

Comment: Sorry I am not getting how to attache fine here